# Output unique combinations in a text file using Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file which contains characters like

[tyy] ........ ue:"yyyu"

[tyy] .......... ue:"yyyu"

[uyy] ...........ue:"yyyu"

[uyy] ........... ue:"xu"

[iyy] ............ ue:"xu"

[uyy] ............ ue:"yyyu"

I have to store the output in another file such that

tyy yyyu

uyy yyyu

uyy xu

iyy xu

Is there a way to select unique combinations using regular expression?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Currently this post is a story, not a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` with a `set`:

```
import re
new_result = {tuple(re.findall('(?<=\[)\w+(?=\])|(?<=")\w+(?=")', i.strip('\n'))) for i in open('filename.txt')}
with open('new_filename.txt', 'w') as f:
 f.write('\n'.join(' '.join(i) for i in new_result))
```

Output:

```
uyy xu
uyy yyyu
iyy xu
tyy yyyu
```

Comment: The output I got was                                                                                               
uyy
tyy

iyy